# How to match string with multiple variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a situation , where i have to render some component (e.g. ) in multiple pages of my app , so i have to check if current path `matches` the paths i provide via `CONSTANTS` .

```
if(this.props.location.pathname.match(CONST1) || this.props.location.pathname.match(CONST2)) {
    render component ...
  }
```

Yes this works well , but i think there is more elegant solution maybe with **Regexp** . Any advice ?
I have also tried this but it didn't work for my situation

```
if(this.props.location.pathname.match(CONST1 || CONST2)){
    render component ...
  }
```

Comment: Just happened to answer a nearly identical question, see the answer there for how to construct such a regex from an array of your `CONST#`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have:

```
let path = this.props.location.pathname;
```

Then we can use  ES5(!) `some` (there also is `every`):

```
if( [CONST1, CONST2].some(x=>path.match(x)) ) {...};
```